# can the size of the same image in MATLAB be shown differently?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I entered an image in MATLAB by the command
a=('Address of the image')
And then I created another variable c as
c=imread('Address of the image')
Now I used the same image in both the cases. When I used the size command it show different sizes for both. How is it possible
size(a) gave different size than size(c).
Although I used the same image in both the cases, for both the variables a and c.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you did exactly what you wrote in your question. Your code would be the following:

```
a = ('onion.png');
c = imread('onion.png');
```

This means that variable `a` is a string represented by some chars and variable `c` is an image represented by an uint8-array.
Applying the `size`-function on them gives different results because it is not the same object at all. This can be verified using the `class`-function.

```
sizeOfA  = size(a)   >>  [1 9]
sizeOfC  = size(c)   >>  [135 198 3]
classOfA = class(a)  >>  char
classOfC = class(c)  >>  uint8
```

**Edit:** What you can do now is to take the string `a` to load the same image. Because just by assigning a filename to a variable, the image is not automatically read. To prove that this creates exactly the same result, we can do this:

```
d = imread(a);
isequal(c,d)
```

Which returns `1` meaning the arrays are equal. Of course they have the same `size` and `class` as the image represented by the variable `c`:

```
sizeOfD  = size(d)   >>  [135 198 3]
classOfD = class(d)  >>  uint8
```

Comment: hahaha I totally missed that `a` was the string of the file name.  I thought `imread` was being doine there too. +1.

Comment: For me this was the only possibility that the size can be different. But it took me a while to see that `imread` has not been executed there ;-)